# Overloading methods with similar signatures

Tags: overloading

I am in a situation where i need to have two overloads for a method that should look like this,

```
void myMethod(string myParam)
{
    // Some code to process myParam
}

void myMethod(string otherParam)
{
    // Another code to process otherParam
}
```

Unfortunately C# compiler doesn't allow this kind of overloading, because it considers the two overloads to be having the same signature, it doesnt really matter if you are going to have different names for the paramters to represent different meanings.

I wonder how should i handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe should create a class wich will extends this one and then you can overload your method.